# Is there a way to add custom routing rules to an Android VPN natively or with a library?

Tags: java, android, networking, routes, vpn

I am trying to route my traffic with custom IP routes within a VPN. I have already had a similar issue with a windows VPN client and I was able to just write a batch file that runs when launching the client and it just runs route add commands.

The problem is it seems that this is impossible to do for Android. I am aware that there is the adb approach, but it gives me permissions errors when attempting to custom add routes. Upon further research it seemed in order to change the routing rules for the IP tables I would have to root my device, this is not an option in my case.

I have looked at the VPN service on the Android Developer page, but I didn't see any way to start adding custom routes to a VPN. I also saw no libraries readily available that provide a method for additionally routing traffic. Perhaps I am missing a piece of the puzzle.

I am still learning about Android Development and this is an issue that I would like to have some input on as I will not be able to run my application through the default VPN without adding my custom rules, and I do not have the ability to change the VPN subnets around to get rid of this issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Android SDK has `addRoute` API to add a route policy through VPN.

But there is no remove route API in the public document.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#addRoute(java.lang.String,%20int)!) is the addRoute documents:

Add a network route to the VPN interface. Both IPv4 and IPv6 routes are supported. Adding a route implicitly allows traffic from that address family (i.e., IPv4 or IPv6) to be routed over the VPN.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but sadly a year ago.